# PHP Contact Form not Sending?

Tags: php

Ive got a contact form that isnt sending but is outputting that the message is sent? Can anybody see a problem?

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "myemail@email.co.uk";

    //begin of HTML message
    $message = "
  From : $name,
  Email: $email,
  Subject: $subject,
  Message: $message ";
   //end of message

    // To send the HTML mail we need to set the Content-type header.
   $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Website Enquiry";


if (isset($_POST['name']))  {

       // now lets send the email.
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?e=Thankyou, we will be in touch shortly.');

} else {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?e=There was an error sending your message, Please try again.');
    }

?>
```

Comment: To make the email API more robust and coherent why not consider implementing [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org)?

Comment: Does this server have an SMTP program installed?

Comment: You need change your condition to `if (mail(...))` for check if mail has been sent or not. The `$_POST` verification may cover all code.

Comment: Try something simpler like `mail('email@domanin.com','subject','message')`. This can tell us if the header is stopping the mail from being sent successfully.

Comment: I smell XSS on your status page.

Comment: regardless of your question - the condition `if isset($_POST['name']))` should wrap the whole script... not just the mail sending.. otherwise you will have warnings when trying to access undefined array members

Comment: Paulo's comment above is right - mail does not die on an error, you need to check that the mail function returns success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "From" header should have a syntactically correct email address. You also need to check the return value of the "mail" function.

```
$header .= "From: Website Enquiry <enquiry@website.com>";
```

PS: Please improve your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter an email at From: in $headers.
Like `$headers .= "From: youremail@provider.com"` or
`$headers .= "From: Website Enquiry <youremail@provider.com>"`

And you should change it to

```
if(mail(...)) {
//success
}
else {
//email failed
}
```